# Read or unread web notifications using public_activity gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, public-activity

I am working with public_activity gem. I have implemented read and unread web notification concept for current_user who logged in the application.

But the scenario is like this,

If i comment to a task, the web notification will come to whomever it is assigned. 
Ex: If user1 commented
    user2, user3, user4, user5 will see the web notification.

If i go with current code. After User2 clicks on that web notification the status will set as read. Now user3, user4, user5 can't see that notification because the status is already read.

How to overcome this scenario...!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean how to implement it without status, but in any way you will need to store this information somewhere.

In short you either create a new model that will hold the notification reference and the user reference and the status, or you will have to make one that holds the notification reference and the user reference without the status and assuming that if there is a record it means that the notification is unread and as soon as the users click/views it you delete the record.

Comment: thats nice, but you must store either who read it or show hasn't in some way. Without a new table I don't see how this can work.